# Linear transformation invertible or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

> Let $ T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a linear transformation defined such that the inner product of $\langle T(v), v \rangle = 0$ for all $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is $T$ invertible or not?

Attempt:
If $T$ has eigenvalues (i.e., it's characteristic polynomial splits), then $0$ is an eigenvalue. This is because $T(v) = kv$ ($k$ is an eigenvalue). Therefore $\langle Tv, v\rangle  = \langle kv, v\rangle  = k\langle v, v\rangle  = 0$. Since $v$ is anything in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is not necessarily $0$, which implies $k = 0$. So if a transformation has a $0$ eigenvalue, it is not invertible.

If $T$ doesn't have eigenvalues, then it's not injective and thus not invertible.

Help! Am I close?

Comment: Use `\to` or `\rightarrow` for $\to$, use `\mathbb{R}` for $\mathbb{R}$, and use `\langle` and `\rangle` for $\langle$ and $\rangle$ (`<` and `>` mean "less than" and "greater than", **not** "angle brackets"). Also, anything that is intended as a mathematical symbol should be in MathJax (i.e., enclosed in dollar signs). [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: Not sure about the "dont have eigenvalues then not injective". But look, you  can consider the transformation which is rotation by $90$ degrees. It doesnt have eigenvalues and elements are orthogonal to their images

Comment: $T$ doesn't have to be invertible because $T$ can be the zero map.  Do you have any more information?  Also, $T$ can fail to have _real_ eigenvalues and still be invertible.  See above comment.

Answer (score 3):

With the given information, we can determine the form of $T$ quite specifically, and see that it will almost always be invertible. We don't need to consider eignevalues at all.

Suppose $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is linear and $\forall v \in \mathbb{R}^2, \langle T(v),v\rangle=0$. Then $T$ is a $\frac{\pi}{2}$ rotation, followed by a scaling.

**Hint:** If we take $e_1,e_2$ to be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $\langle T(e_1),e_1\rangle = 0 = \langle T(e_2),e_2\rangle$. You can use this to say something about the values of $T(e_i)$. But we also have that $\langle T(e_1+e_2),e_1+e_2\rangle=0$, which tells us something else. (Using the fact that $T$ is linear so $T(v+w)=T(v)+T(w)$.)